# I uninstalled xorg and can't use Ubuntu Desktop without wayland

Tags: 18.04, xorg

I stupidly ran the command `sudo apt remove k*` to uninstall kde. This however also uninstalled parts of xorg/x server/x11. I don't know what it uninstalled, as I know nothing about linux. I have tried running multiple commands like `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt install xorg`. It also gives a message about packages which should be removed, however these are nvidia ones and I'm worried to do so. I can only use Wayland, which is incovenient.[image: n]

Comment: I would suggest to run `sudo apt install xserver-xorg`. That should install everything else. But the command was wrong and could remove much more.

Comment: Look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see what really got uninstalled.

Comment: @Jos What got removed is here https://gist.github.com/homelyseven250/c40f8558c3057e0b1177d63ef01bff13

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried that, but it just outputted this: https://gist.github.com/homelyseven250/1473a7fe33332d20f77400852cb8c1aa

Comment: You can look into `/var/log/apt/history.log` and check what was removed. But it will be a lot easier and faster to re-install the system and stop running commands you don't understand.

Comment: Contrary to @Pilot6's recommendation, I would reinstall the packages that were removed, and check that everything is as before.

Comment: @Jos This is not contrary ;-) I suggested to check what was removed and install it back. But if it doesn't solve the problem, further investigation with limited skills doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: I tried this, but I was met with the issue of some packages not being found:
E: Unable to locate package xserverxorginputall
for example.

Comment: You must have inadvertently removed some `-`s; the name of the package is `xserver-xorg-input-all`.

Comment: Thank you so much Jos and @Pilot6 - I managed to get it to work after using Visual Studio to remove all the brackets, commas etc. I think the reason the dashes were wrong was because I used incorrect regex. I can now login to x11, but have inadvertently installed Unity Desktop and Plasma. What is the **correct** way to remove these, or should I open a new question?

Comment: it's a bit of detective work, think to sort things by version probably best, but removing any of them completely will probably be impossible

Comment: I managed to get rid of Unity (not defualt) desktop by running `sudo apt remove unity`, then `sudo apt autoremove`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find what I did, but this helped me at a later date, when I did something similar.

I followed the instructions from https://serverfault.com/a/703266, but I've posted them here:

1. I ran
   `awk '!/^Start|^Commandl|^End|^Upgrade:|^Error:/ { gsub( /\([^()]*\)/ ,"" );gsub(/ ,/," ");sub(/^Install:/,""); print}' /var/log/apt/history.log`. This command gets the latest remove, then removes any nonsense.
2. Run `apt install [The output]` of the above command.